# battery not loading on film on camera

Tags: battery

I have a Praktica M60 26mm Glass Lens camera and the battery ran out and i had to change it. when putting in new batteries, it won't work. any suggestions? i can't wind the film and it says 0 (backwards C)! help! i've tried many different batteries.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the batteries.  The film needs to be removed for the camera to reset.   I believe that camera has auto rewind so it will have to be opened in a darkbox or darkroom and the film will need to be manually pulled out and rewound back into the cassette.   If you have a local camera ahop you should ask them to do it because these point n click cameras will often lock the advance/rewind gears.  An experienced lab worker can remove the film saefly.   The camera should work fine after you load another roll.   If you don't have a lab near you let me know and I'll gladly rescue your film for you.